# Query Contacts By Multiple LOOKUP_KEY

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

The following code queries great for a single LOOKUP_KEY.

```
private final String lookup1 = "0r1-2E3C384E4846";
private final String lookup2 = "0r2-442C4E523A2C3E2C443450";
private final String lookup3 = "0r3-402C423442";

/////////

Uri lookUpUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(23, lookup1);
Uri res = ContactsContract.Contacts.lookupContact(getContentResolver(), lookUpUri);
Cursor contactCursor = getContentResolver().query(res, null, null, null, null);
contactCursor.moveToFirst();
Log.i("APP", "length: " + contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)) );
```

However, as the code might suggest I need to query for "x" number of contacts. Is there a way to query for all of these at once without having to loop over them? Looping will be horribly inefficient so I really want to avoid it.

Thanks a ton gang!

Comment: I'm in the same senario. Did you find an efficient way to perform the query?